# Flybe just cancelled my return flight. Will they refund that part of the trip?

Tags: international-travel, cancellations, refunds

Yesterday I received an email from Flybe that my return flight in January has been cancelled. They said that I need to book another ticket and they will refund. But I'm not clear about how much would it be.

The ticket I bought is from SOU (Southampton) to AGP (Malaga) and return.. Now I have to find alternatives for the return and I found from AGP (Malaga) to LGW (Gatwick) which far (2 hours by train from Southampton).

The original ticket I paid was £410 (2 adults & 1 baby). now for the return to Gatwick I found it for £100.. (Plus I need to buy train tickets). What I paid for the return flight is roughly £190. so if the refund me only £100 they will still owe me £90.

I know calling can help.. the problem is that every time I called is 30 minutes waiting to be answered. So I want to know my options.

Comment: I believe you should be entitled to a full refund of the entire fare - and then you could book another return travel.

Comment: Well They asked me to book another flight first and then send them the receipt, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: What did they say when you asked them?

Comment: Oh, then maybe what they meant is that you should buy the return flight elsewhere and they will reimburse you the cost of the return flight with the other airline.

Comment: @DJClayworth It was my wife who talked to them this morning because I had to leave to work.

Comment: @AleksG But that's what I think is not fair.. the other flight is going to be cheaper because is very far away..

Comment: Be sure you have read through the [Conditions of Carriage](http://www.flybe.com/ticket-rules/conditions-of-carriage.htm), which you agreed to when you originally purchased the tickets. Section 10.2.1 addresses your scenario.

Comment: @choster thanks for that link! "pnuts" I don't think is going to be the whole amount as I will be doing the outbound trip, is the inbound that has been cancelled

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory if an airline (or anyone else) is unable to supply the services you paid for they should offer you the option of cancelling the entire trip for a full refund. As pnuts points out, this is written into your conditions of carriage. However pretty frequently airlines try to get you to keep some of trip and give you only a partial refund in order to keep as much of your money as they can. They frequently offer you the partial refund in a way that makes it sound as if that's the normal, or possibly the only, way to go.

Make one more call to the airline and get them to spell out in detail what the options are. Ask them specifically if you can get a full refund (and if not read them the conditions of carriage) and how much they will give you back if you still take the outbound leg.

In then meantime check your options for booking only a new return flight, or new flights both ways. Ideally if you can be in a position to know what is available when you call, you should be able to decide on the spot whether you want to take a full refund or partial refund. Making it clear that you have the option to change the entire flight might make them offer you more refund if you stay on the outbound flight.

Comment: So you are saying the should refund the whole trip even if only one part of it was cancelled? I'll definitely call them later again. Thanks for you answer.. that's the kind information I needed before I call them

Comment: Since the flights are all within the EU, EU-261 will also dictate the very minimum they have to offer in this situation